# Convert date in php

Tags: php

How to convert "Thu Oct 28 16:33:29 +0000 2010 " to like  "Oct 28,2010 at 10:33PM"

Answer (score 7):

Use the [strtotime function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) combined with the [date function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
echo date("jS F, Y", strtotime("11/25/10"));
// outputs 25th November, 2010
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Thu Oct 28 16:33:29 +0000 2010', 'D M j h:m:s O Y');
echo $date->format('M d,Y, h:mA');
```

Relevant docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)